# What determines the price of an apartment?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

One of my friends bought an apartment in the same complex as me and his was roughly $9,000 less than mine and he has a better view of the city!

What determines the value of an apartment online?

Comment: Rockstart determines the value. By what logic, other than garage space, is beyond me. One apartment next almost next to an LS customs costs ~$100k less than one thats about 4 blocks further away with the same garage space. It's the same with missions. Some missions take ~5 minutes to complete and you get $18k and some 2k exp and other take ~20 minutes and you get $2k and some 500 exp.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that the prices are organized by building (which scales to garage space/location), and then floor.  IE two apartments in the same building will be price scaled to the floor number.  I would recommend googling around "gta online apartment view" as people have compiled lists of views from the high-end apartments so that you can choose accordingly as any 10-car garage apartment is exactly the same inside.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the two you're talking about, I believe the one that's $391,000 does have the better view of the two. *That's just my opinion*

There's nothing really different about it other than that. These are the Eclipse Towers in the Rockford Hills, which is the most expensive part of town. Then a couple blocks south you have apts that are around 200,000 but don't have a good view of the city.  I decided with the eclipse towers as well because you just can't beat the price for what you can get. $300,000 apt. plus 150,000 garage plus an awesome view.  The garage you get with it is better than the 10-car garage that's $125,000, and its on the other side of town.

Answer (score 1):

The price of each apartment is set by Rockstar.

The prices of the apartments doesn't change. You and you friend just bought two different apartments. When you open up your phone, select internet. Then select the "money, economy" or whatever it's called tab. Then select the Real Estate link. From there, you should be able to choose something like; "See avaible estate" or something along those lines. There you will see, that you can buy more than a single apartment at each complex, all at different prices.